# Basis of defined subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Find a basis for the subspace $W$
 of $\mathbb{R}^4 $ , where $$W = \left\{\ \begin{bmatrix}s+4t &\\6s  &\\t  &\\s\end{bmatrix}: t,s \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

I can find basis given specific values for a subset, but the variables are really throwing me off. 
Sorry for not showing work. This one really stumped me.

Comment: A basis for $W$ is a set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ (where $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\in W$ are all non-null and not necessarily all distinct) such that $W=\{\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\lambda_3v_3+\lambda_4v_4\colon \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4\in \mathbb R\}$. Now note that, by isolating the variables you can write $$W = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}s&\\6s \\0\\s\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}4t &\\0\\t  &\\0\end{bmatrix}\colon t,s \in \mathbb{R} \right\}_.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map
$$ \begin{bmatrix}s\\t \end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}s+4t &\\6s  &\\t  &\\s\end{bmatrix}
$$
is a bijection. Thus it maps bases to bases. Plugging in $[s,t] = [1,0], [0,1]$ results in a basis of $W$.

Comment: So there is only one basis vector? $$\begin{bmatrix} s
\\ t

\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} $$ so... $$\begin{bmatrix} 5\\6\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ is a basis? Is it the only one?

Comment: @RobertHosking No. Plugging in $[s,t] = [1,0]$ gives one basis vector, while $[0,1]$ gives the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: convert the vector to

\begin{bmatrix}s + 4t \\ 6s + 0t \\ 0s + t \\ s + 0t \end{bmatrix}

then create two vectors, one multiplied by $s$ and the other multiplied by $t$ that when added together yields the above vector.  The two vectors will form a basis for your solution set